# Getting error: NullReferenceException was not handled

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nullreferenceexception

```
string filename = o.FileName;
string[] textlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
string[] mainAndSublines = null;
int i = 0;

foreach(string textline in textlines)
{
   if (textline.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
   {
      i++;
   }

   mainAndSublines[i] = textlines[i];   //Getting error, NullReferenceException was not handled
}
```

I am getting thee error:

> NullReferenceException was not handled

Comment: There are two types of lines in the text file, 1. starts without a blank space, 2.  starts with a blank space, i am storing each of them in an array.  example,

First line
 i belong to firstline, Mark 
 i belong to firstline, Joy
Second line
 i belong to secondline, Mark 
 i belong to secondline, Joy

looking for, 
array[0]=> First line
 i belong to firstline, Mark 
 i belong to firstline, Joy
array[1]=> Second line
 i belong to secondline, Mark 
 i belong to secondline, Joy

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps you could update the question with the missing information instead of writing it in a comment? Then you could use formatting to make the description more clear and hopefully(!) it will make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

You have initialized mainAndSublines to null.

If you know the desired size in advance use this:

```
string[] mainAndSublines = new string[100];
```

If you don't know the size you want in advance, use a dynamically resizing container such as a List:

```
List<string> mainAndSublines = new List<string>();
```

Comment: List is the most suitable solution here

Comment: `<pedant>`Actually he *has* initializes `mainAndSublines` to a value, explicitly - the null value. It's still a value :)`</pedant>`

Comment: Jon: He has assigned value to variable, but hasn't initialized it as an array, has he?

Comment: @abatishchev: No, but Mark claimed "you haven't initialized mainAndSublines to any value" which isn't true. If he'd said, "you haven't created an array and assigned a value to mainAndSublines to refer to that array" that would have been a different matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because your array `mainAndSublines` is null and you can't access an element of an array that is null ...

Answer (score 1):

You've actually got *two* problems here - one is that you're trying to set values into a null array, and the other is how you're trying to find whether the first character of the line is a space.

I would use a `List<String>` for the non-space-starting lines, as you can't tell how many there will be, but then you're *assuming* that every line will be non-empty. Fortunately it's easy to fix this using `StartsWith`.

I'd *then* use LINQ if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, which makes the whole thing *really* simple:

```
List<string> mainAndSublines = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                                   .Where(x => !x.StartsWith(" "))
                                   .ToList();
```

In .NET 4 you can make this more memory-efficient using [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead of `File.ReadAllLines` - this streams the file instead of loading the whole thing into memory to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize second array too, as you did with first, probably equal by size.

```
string[] mainAndSublines = new string[textlines.Length];
```

But the most suitable solution here will be Mark's one - auto-resizable container.